# html5 website showcase?

Tags: html

websites similar to bentheboydguard.com or the latest NIKE html5 website?
which websites lists all the latest well disgned html5 websites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.apple.com/html5/

http://html5gallery.com/

http://101besthtml5sites.com/

http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/

and similar to Ben the Body Guard:
http://lostworldsfairs.com/atlantis/ (this is part of the ie9 showcase)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.nytimes.com/chrome/

http://entanglement.gopherwoodstudios.com/

http://www.tweetdeck.com/chrome/

also check it out chrome web store, there you can find more apps:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore